# is a variable stored as a memory refrence in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have read that a variable is stored as a memory reference in js.

So for `var a = 5`, the memory location with value `5` is assigned to `a`.

I tried running this on node.js:

```
var a = 5;
var b = {
  val: a
};
a = 6;
```

I expect `b.val` to be `6` but is `5`,

If I run:

```
var a = 5;
var b = {
  val: a
};
var c = {
  value: b
}
b.val = 6;
```

Than `c.value.val` is `6`.

If they are all memory objects, why is there a difference in outputs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In javascript when you assign an `object` to another `variable`, its `memory reference` will be shared. It will not create a copy. At the same time, `primitive values` will act exact opposite to that. It will create a copy when it got assigned to another one `variable`.

Also you have to note about this odd situation,

```
var x = { a: 10 };
var y = x;
x = 5;
```

At a first look, after hearing a basic explanation about objects, everyone(new learners) would tell that, `y` will contain `5`. But that is wrong. `y` will have the older value, that is `{a:10}`. Because at this context, `x`'s old reference will be cut off and new value will be assigned with new memory location. But `Y` will hold its reference that was given by `x`.

Answer (score 2):

> I have read that a variable is stored as a memory reference in js.

Well, yes, all variables are basically references to memory - in all languages.

> So for `var a = 5`, the memory location with value 5 is assigned to a.

I would say "the value `5` is written to the memory location with the name `a`".

> I expect b.val to be 6 but is 5

How so? `… val: a …` means "take the value from the memory location with the name `a` and create a property named `val` with it. The value that is stored there is `5`.

In JavaScripts, only objects are values that *reference* more memory (specifically, their respective properties), and passing around such a reference value will always reference the same set of properties (the "object"). All other values - so called *primitive* values - are just immutable values, no references.